# Guides or samples for NSRuleEditor?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nscontrol

`NSRuleEditor` looks like a pretty powerful class and it looks like stuff like iTunes Smart Playlists or Finder Smart Folders are using it.
(*I reckon it should be called NSSmartRuleEditor...*)

But is there **any** kind of documentation apart form the reference?

Some kind of sample code or guide would be nice but it doesn't look like ADC has anything to offer.. as of now `NSRuleEditor` seems to be the least documented control in Cocoa!

Anybody knowing of any Open Source projects using the controls, blog articles, etc.?

Comment: Wow, that popular, ey? :-)

Comment: I can't post anything useful now (I will do tomorrow), but I did find an example project on either MacOSX.com or MacRumors.com forums.

Comment: much appreciated - still no sample code found yet..

Comment: Ahem... A few months later, https://github.com/danieljfarrell/NSRuleEditorTest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should probably be looking for NSPredicateEditor rather than NSRuleEditor.  NSPredicateEditor is a subclass of NSRuleEditor and is what is used for editing "smart" playlists and the such.

Apple's Documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSPredicateEditor_class/Reference/NSPredicateEditor.html

Sample App:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/PhotoSearch/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: NSPredicateEditor isn't terribly difficult to use.  I have found many other examples on StackOverflow as well.  Here's a good example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5642681/nspredicateeditor-in-xcode-4